# Not able to Build .ear file to have Text file encoding=UTF-8

Tags: java, ant, utf-8, websphere

I have some code deals with Chinese characters. In my eclipse I set project -> Properties -> Resource -> Text file `encoding = UTF-8`. And I use `javac.encoding=UTF-8` to build my .ear through ANT. When run my .ear in Websphere7. But somehow the Text file is not encoded as UTF-8 anymore.

The problem is in UTF-8, `String.getBytes(`).length will return 3 for each Chinese character, but without UTF-8, all Chinese characters become "?", so `String.getBytes()`.length returns 1 for each character. I need to find a way to make it to return 3.

What am I missing? Is there a setting in Websphere I need to set?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading the file? Did you read with UTF-8 charset?

```
InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread()
        .getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/app/myfile.txt");
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
```

Comment: Actually I am running SOAP client to pull data from a 3rd party company SOAP Server. The data is in Chinese.